# Adding Firebase package to Xcode with SPM results in an increase from 200 to 1800 build files

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager

I followed this official guide to adding Firebase to my project:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup?hl=en#swift

Once you add `https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk` in Swift Package Manager, it prompts you a window to select which sub-packages of Firebase you actually want. I selected 4 of them:

- FirebaseAnalytics
- FirebaseFirestore
- FirebaseStorage
- FirebaseAuth

Before this, my project had 2 package dependencies. After resolving, my project now suddenly has **15(!) packages**  installed (black are the two installed by me):

[image]

And my build files increased from ~90-150 to **1800(!)**:

[image]
(which now takes about 10 times longer for any preview or simulator to run)

I have used the exact same Firebase dependencies in AndroidStudio for my Android version and there it never destroyed my build like that.

**This looks like a bug to me. Is this how it normally goes? Why are there so many third-party packages contained in there?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The packages shown are Firebase or Firebase dependencies except for `SwiftProtobuf`.  A significant majority of the increased number of files and build time comes from Firestore and its dependencies which is substantially bigger than anything else in Firebase.

See a related issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6564

Comment: That is unfortunate, thank you for the clarification. One question, and I hope it is not a stupid one: this huge amount of files only affects my local build time while coding, not the app performance on my user's devices, right?

Comment: Right - and it should only affect clean build time. Incremental builds should still be fast.